# Trying to create array from child objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, angular7

I have an array that has a top level I need to get rid of, I am using Angular7 and I am not sure how to go about pulling out the child objects from this array.  I would like to get rid of the "toplevel" level so you just have the objects with properties.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
    "toplevel": [
        {
            "SetName": "name1",
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "managingEntitySource": "blah blah blah",
            "effectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "terminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemEffectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemTerminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "comments": "blah blah blah",
            "lastProcessDate": "01/01/9999"
        },
        {
            "SetName": "name2",
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "managingEntitySource": "blah blah blah",
            "effectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "terminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemEffectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemTerminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "comments": "blah blah blah",
            "lastProcessDate": "01/01/9999"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I am looking for after:

```
[
        {
            "SetName": "name1",
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "managingEntitySource": "blah blah blah",
            "effectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "terminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemEffectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemTerminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "comments": "blah blah blah",
            "lastProcessDate": "01/01/9999"
        },
        {
            "SetName": "name2",
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "managingEntitySource": "blah blah blah",
            "effectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "terminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemEffectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemTerminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "comments": "blah blah blah",
            "lastProcessDate": "01/01/9999"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Include an example output. It's not clear what "pulling out the child objects from this array" means.

Comment: posted example of output

Comment: Just access the object property? `obj.topLevel`

Comment: The problem I am having is when I try to do a find in Angular I am getting undefined because its not looking in the next level.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var jsonObject = {
    "toplevel": [
        {
            "SetName": "name1",
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "managingEntitySource": "blah blah blah",
            "effectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "terminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemEffectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemTerminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "comments": "blah blah blah",
            "lastProcessDate": "01/01/9999"
        },
        {
            "SetName": "name2",
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "managingEntitySource": "blah blah blah",
            "effectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "terminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemEffectiveDate": "01/01/9999",
            "systemTerminationDate": "01/01/9999",
            "comments": "blah blah blah",
            "lastProcessDate": "01/01/9999"
        }
    ]
};

var innerArray = jsonObject.toplevel;

console.log(innerArray);
```